# Joomla Template - site design not updating

Tags: templates, cache, helix3

I am new to using Joomla, I have a temporary hosting account on Demojoomla.

I have installed a template called Helix

When I go to Extensions > Templates > Styles I can click on my template and configure it, and save the changes.

Then, when I refresh the site, nothing has changed.

But when I close the template editing screen and refresh the page, I can see the changes, but only until I refresh again or choose a different menu option, then it reverts back to the old design.

If I then disable the template and enable one of the standard Joomla templates instead, when I refresh the page, the display reverts to the Joomla template, but if I then navigate to a different page, I get the Helix template back again!

Some links give my modified Helix template, others the default Helix template, others a standard Joomla template, it's pretty random and different each time. It's unusable.

Have I done something wrong in config, or is there a serious bug in Joomla?

Comment: just sounds like your hitting cached pages, click a new link, then refresh a few times. hold down shift and refresh, or f5

Comment: Already tried. Old design seems to be cached at the Joomla end, even if I delete all caches there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Demo Joomla sites are hosted by SiteGround and may have [SiteGround dynamic cache](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/supercacher/dynamic_cache) enabled by default.

You could try temporarily disabling "System - jSGCache" in Extensions -> Plugins if this plugin exists and is enabled.

Comment: Awesome - did the trick! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to note:

- Templates can be assigned per page/menu item.
- You can have many template styles assigned to different pages
- We don't know what exactly changes you do on the template and if what you do is right or can be applicable on the front-end pages you are viewing. So in conjunction with the above 2 items and by studying the documentation of your template, make sure you are using it right.

As for the possibility of cached content:

- Many templates implement features like compressing, minifying, caching of their assets. Many others use modern technologies like less or sass for their css, that will compile the css when this is requested. So css changes may not be visible until the engine compile a new css file.
- Read also this: **[CSS Change won't apply - Where could the cache be?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/18842/where-could-the-cache-be)**